# Excel - String Split by regex or similar

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to split a string and get the RIGHT part of a  of a string that looks like this "10.0.17763.987"  i.e.(**17763.987**). I'm  using  this  formula: `=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("10.0.",B2)-4)`.  but this breaks when  search term  is ; "**6.3.92852.445**" .
How can i improve   my formula  to   be able to  get me the right result no matter  the  characters  in the beginning ?

The only common  patter i see in data  is " **XX.XX.  or   X.X.**"    (two dots is the common )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MID with FIND and SUBSTITUTE:

```
=MID(B2,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","}}}",2))+1,999)
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason i  was not able to use the formula you sent in a single  cell, however  i was able to  use  a helper cell substituting  the second. with the "**}}}**"  (`=SUBSTITUTE(B2,".","}}}",2)`) and then I  used  `=RIGHT(P2, LEN(P2)-FIND("}}}", P2)-2)`.  why was i not able to use  in same formula

Comment: You Are the  Man !! Thank you very much